# Gluing genus 0 Bessel curve to get genus 1 curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, algebraic-curves

I was attending some seminar where the following was mentioned, I never understood things in deep. So I ask the community to give me reference or explain.
Let
$${x}^{3}{y}^{2}-{x}^{2}-x-1 =0 $$
$$ y^2  = \frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^2} +\frac{1}{x} \tag{*}       $$
denote algebraic curve, the genus of the algebraic curve is 1. And the corresponding picture [image]
denote the image of the curve, but I am not sure what is the 0, $\infty$ represent. I picked a particular curve but a general curve can be represented by
$$ y^2 =\frac{t}{x^3}+\frac{b}{x^2} +\frac{t}{x}\tag{**}  $$
where $t,b$ parameters.

Now the part I want to know what we mean by gluing of two curves of genus zero of the form
$$y^2 = \frac{x+b}{4x^2}\tag{***} $$
where $b$ is constant
we can get a genus 1 curve we discussed above. [image] ?

What I think is the following, not having much confidence to state it mathematically.
Let's denote the curve (***) in $y_1 , x_1$ coordinate and (***) $y_2 , x_2$, then we can multiply two equation  (*) and then identifying $y_1 = f(y_2)$  and $x_1 = g(x_2)$.
where $f,g$ are some polynomials. I didn't came up with a solution of this the